# Are Comodo's code signing certificates valid?

Tags: windows, certificate

I recall a while back Comodo got hacked and browsers / platforms stopped accepting their SSL certificates are valid. I've looked around and can't find the answer -- what about their code signing certificates? Are those still considered valid and usable? They are by far the cheapest I can find, and I need a code signing certificate for my Windows program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer myself. Yes, they are still valid.